# drupal files directory

Tags: files

I have a Drupal site and I am unsure of how the files directory works.

It seems at the moment all files uploaded to the site go to the files directory. If I create a new node and upload fish.png which goes to the files directory another user also uploading a file called fish.png will overwrite my file.

Have I missed something here???

Comment: The file will not be replaced. The new one will be renamed to fish_1.png and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the how to set the file system settings on [File system settings](http://drupal.org/node/15368). You can also change it, and specify the other folder for the files as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> If I create a new node and upload fish.png which goes to the files directory another user also uploading a file called fish.png will overwrite my file.

The file is renamed, and an number is added to make the filename unique. When an uploaded file is saved, [file_save_upload()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7) indirectly calls [file_create_filename()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_filename/7), which contains the following code.

```
  if (file_exists($destination)) {
    // Destination file already exists, generate an alternative.
    $pos = strrpos($basename, '.');
    if ($pos !== FALSE) {
      $name = substr($basename, 0, $pos);
      $ext = substr($basename, $pos);
    }
    else {
      $name = $basename;
      $ext = '';
    }

    $counter = 0;
    do {
      $destination = $directory . $separator . $name . '_' . $counter++ . $ext;
    } while (file_exists($destination));
  }
```